# Union Distinct rows but order them by number of occurrences in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, union

I have the following query:

```
SELECT o.id,o.name FROM object o 
WHERE 
    (
        o.description LIKE '%Black%' OR
        o.name LIKE '%Black%'
    ) 
UNION ALL
SELECT o2.id,o2.name FROM object o2
WHERE 
    (
        o2.description LIKE '%iPhone%' OR
        o2.name LIKE '%iPhone%'
    )
```

Which procude the following:

```
id  name
2   New Black iPhone
1   New White iPhone
2   New Black iPhone
```

I would like to UNION DISTINCT, but I would also like the result ordered by the number of occurrences of each identical row (primary: id).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can group your result on id and name columns and see how many occurences each distinct value has.
then you can order them by most occurences appearing first `order by count(*) desc`

```
select id, name, count(*) as occurences
from (
    SELECT o.id,o.name FROM object o 
    WHERE 
        (
            o.description LIKE '%Black%' OR
            o.name LIKE '%Black%'
        ) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT o2.id,o2.name FROM object o2
    WHERE 
        (
            o2.description LIKE '%iPhone%' OR
            o2.name LIKE '%iPhone%'
        ) 
)
group by id, name
order by count(*) desc
```

this will return

```
id  name              occurences
2   New Black iPhone  2
1   New White iPhone  1
```